# Есть ли возможность снимать значение NSSlider с текущего значения ползунка?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, slider, mac

Есть возможность считать текущее значение со слайдера без нажатия на него? то есть слайдер движется по какому-то алгоритму. и надо снять текущее значение без нажатия мышкой по нему.

Сейчас я считываю значение вот так

`float currentSlide = [_AnimSlide doubleValue];`

Однако значение не считывается, пока не нажму по слайдеру мышкой.

Comment: везде пишут, что doubleValue должен работать. а что он вам возвращает?

Comment: я и использую doubleValue. Фишка в том что он снимает значение когда я отпускаю мышку. а нужно чтобы снимал значение когда просто значения меняются на слайдере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно выставить флаг `_AnimSlide.continuous = YES`, тогда при любых изменениях положения слайдера будет обновляться его значение.